# calling preferenceFragment from navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation, fragment

I'm new to Android programming and I have implemented a navigation bar to switch between fragments.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ItemFragment fragment = new ItemFragment();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

But now I added a settings Button in the nav bar to get to a settingsFragment, which is implemented using preferenceFragment from android.preference.PreferenceFragment. Unfortunately  this collides with android.support.v4.app.Fragment. So I am wondering if this is even the right way to do it. My question is, what construct should I use, to get to settings from the navigation bar (as in most google apps). Is it even prefenceFragment or something else?

Greets

edit: Found a solution here [Android: Preference Fragment with a Navigation Drawer's Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045495/android-preference-fragment-with-a-navigation-drawers-fragment)

Comment: Try adding and not replacing

Comment: Do you mean transaction.add(Fragment fragment, String tag)...I get "can resolve methode", when I fill it with settings as fragment and some string.

Comment: Try this: `transaction.add(0, fragment ).commit();`

Comment: still "can resolve methode". SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment and I guess this does not match.