# PreferenceFragment via NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-preferences

I try create PreferenceFragment which must be opened via NavigationDrawer, but it does'nt work normal.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
...
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

private void setupNavigationDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                setTitle(item.getTitle());
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                ...
                    case R.id.nav_one:
                        setFragment(3);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_two:
                        setFragment(4);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_settings:
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.content_main, new SettingFragment())
                                .commit();
                        return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
public void setFragment(int position){
        mFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position){
            ...
                fragment = new OneFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new TwoFragment();
                break;
            case 5:
                break;

        }

        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
        mFragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**SettingFragment.java**

```
public class SettingFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        public SettingFragment() {

        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        }
    }
}
```

And it looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzgAh.png)
The SettingFragment is inserted on top of the rest fragments and not destroyed after clicking other fragments.

This similar question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045495/android-preference-fragment-with-a-navigation-drawers-fragment)

not helped me.

Does anyone know the solution?

**Solution**: Use PreferenceFragmentCompat instead PreferenceFragment.

Comment: `getFragmentManager()`, `getSupportFragmentManager()` – You're using two different `FragmentManager`s. They are not going to replace or remove each other's `Fragment`s. These days, you should be using only support library `Fragment`s.

Comment: @MikeM. yes, but getSupportFragmentManager() required android.support.v4.app.Fragment, but my Fragment extends PreferenceFragment

Comment: Change it to extend [`PreferenceFragmentCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat) instead.

Comment: Also, I can't really tell what you're trying to do with `SettingFragment`, but it's just immediately replacing itself with `MyPreferenceFragment`, so it's rather pointless. Was that just an attempt at a fix?

Comment: @MikeM. Ok. I edited code. So it happend due to different FragmentManager? Now i will try change it to PreferenceFragmentCompat and see what happens.

Comment: @MikeM. I changed to PreferenceFragmentCompat and it works. Thank you very much.